# Is it possible to fix OutOfMemory error by specify GC flags?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, out-of-memory

Is specifying GC flags a possible solution to OutOfMemory exceptions, or does it have no impact or whether the program will run out of memory?

The GC flags in question are: -`XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` and `-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode`

I'm asking because I thought the above flags (and GC flags in general) are there to tune JVM performance (in relation to it's response/speed), but they have no impact on reducing the minimum memory requirements of your program. In other words, if there is not enough memory for the program to run to completion (e.g. running into OutOfMemory exception), no amount of JVM tuning will resolve that.

Comment: The way to fix an `OutOfMemoryError` is to (a) use less memory or (b) provide more memory. Usually the problem is due to a bug and fixing it fixes (a). A bug cannot be fixed by (b).

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answers. I posted my original question because my team recently encountered such an error and we made 2 code changes, along with the above GC flags. The end result is that the changes seemed to dramatically reduce the amount of memory used (max. committed and max. used are both a lot lower). Everyone was attributing "fix" to the GC flags since GC is now occurring more frequently and our memory usage is peaking at lower levels. But I am trying to convince everyone that the GC flags did not and cannot resolve the OutOfMemory errors. Our code changes did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get `OutOfMemoryError: heap space`, there is nothing you can do. JVM will never throw this before GCing the last byte out of the heap.

However, if you get `OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`, then there may be something you can still do about it because this is a "soft" error and there may be a config setting that will lessen the GC overhead. Quite improbable, I must add, but at least possible in theory.

Answer (score 1):

If there is memory leak in your code, those flags are not useful.

As per [Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#available_collectors.selecting):

> Unless your application has rather strict pause time requirements, first run your application and allow the VM to select a collector. If necessary, adjust the heap size to improve performance. If the performance still does not meet your goals, then use the following guidelines as a starting point for selecting a collector.
>
> If the application has a small data set (up to approximately 100MB), then
>
> - select the serial collector with `-XX:+UseSerialGC`.
>
> If the application will be run on a single processor and there are no pause time requirements, then
>
> - let the VM select the collector, or
> - select the serial collector with `-XX:+UseSerialGC`.
>
> If (a) peak application performance is the first priority and (b) there are no pause time requirements or pauses of one second or longer are acceptable, then
>
> - let the VM select the collector, or
> - select the parallel collector with `-XX:+UseParallelGC` and (optionally) enable parallel compaction with `-XX:+UseParallelOldGC`.
>
> If response time is more important than overall throughput and garbage collection pauses must be kept shorter than approximately one second, then
>
> - select the concurrent collector with `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`. If only one or two processors are available, consider using incremental mode, described below.

Answer (score 1):

The only tuning parameter which matters is the maximum memory. i.e. `-Xmx` or `-mx`  If your program has run out of memory due to a memory leak, even raising this won't help.

BTW: Setting memory tuning can actually reduce the amount of memory you can use before you run out.  E.g. if you set the NewSize, this can limit how much the JVM can resize the generations to use all the memory.

In general, the less options you use the better if you want to use all your memory.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your comment regarding NewSize and "Setting memory tuning can actually reduce the amount of memory you can use before you run out"? Is there a scenario where the JVM won't use all of the available heap because it is not in the "correct gen" space?

Comment: If you set the maximum heap size to 2 GB and minimum new size to say 1 GB, then you will have a tenured size of up to 1 GB. If your tenured space fills up, you can get an OutOfMemoryError even if there is free space in the new generations. The reason this is not normally a problem is that without setting the new size, the JVM can grow the tenured size as required by shrinking the new generations.